# I am facing an issue on shogun interface

Tags: cmake, shogun, cmake-modules

This is the error which I am facing with:

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 15 2017
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:174 (file):
file failed to open for writing (No such file or directory):

C:/Users/nEW u/Desktop/shogun_stable/shogun/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:27 (project)

CMake Error: Could not open file for write in copy operation C:/Users/nEW u/Desk top/shogun_stable/shogun/build/CMakeFiles/3.13.4/CMakeSystem.cmake.tmp
CMake Error: : System Error: No such file or directory
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/CMakeDetermineSys tem.cmake:186 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:27 (project)

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:27 (project):
Failed to make directory:

C:/Users/nEW u/Desktop/shogun_stable/shogun/build/CMakeFiles/3.13.4
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
CMake Error: Cannot open file for write: C:/Users/nEW u/Desktop/shogun_stable/sh ogun/build/CMakeCache.txt.tmp
CMake Error: : System Error: No such file or directory
CMake Error: Unable to open cache file for save. C:/Users/nEW u/Desktop/shogun_s table/shogun/build/CMakeCache.txt
CMake Error: : System Error: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you verified that the file cmake is complaining about exists?  Have you asked for help from shogun developers/support?

Comment: One of the error message is "Could not open file for write in copy operation C:/Users/nEW u/Desk top/shogun_stable/shogun/build/CMakeFiles/3.13.4/CMakeSystem.cmake.tmp". Do you have given file or, at least, directories which contains it? Directory component "Desk top" seems to actually be "Desktop", so your configure log is probably **not exact**. Please, recheck that you show us the exact configure log which you got.